# Check cin from another program without waiting in OSX

Tags: c++, cin

In C++ on OSX, how do we check std::cin for data without waiting?

The expected data is not coming from a keyboard or human, but from a program that has started my executable and talks to my executable via stdin.  This 'parent' program will tell me to start a long process, may interrupt, and I may periodically send data back to it via stdout, therefore the checking of stdin must not block.  I'm using XCode.

So far I have attempted to test via the following, neither of which seem to work:

```
//Return true if there is data waiting version 1
return (std::cin.peek() != EOF);
```

---

```
//Return true if there is data waiting version 2
return (std::cin.rdbuf() && std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() >= 0);
```

Comment: Pretty much all input operations block.  What you can do to work around that is spin up a thread, get the input in the thread, and then in your main thread you can check and see if that thread is ready (has read in data)

Comment: Please instruct me how this post could be improved if you're going to DV.

Comment: @NathanOliver That may well be the only solution.

Comment: You could go down to a lower level, and check if the file-descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` is readable with e.g. the [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) function. With a zero timeout it can be used to poll without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

To fill out the idea mentioned in a comment, the easiest way since C++11 is simply to start a thread that waits for input and, when it is received, add it to a shared queue container.  Doing so requires use of mutex locking & unlocking.  This container then can be used to check if empty and, if it has something in it, the data can just be read and popped off of the front of the queue.  Something like the following:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex qmutex;
std::queue<std::string> queue;

void listen() {
    std::string sin;
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> sin;     // Thread will wait here for stdin to arrive
        qmutex.lock();
        queue.push(sin);
        qmutex.unlock();
    }
}

void mainstuff() {
    std::thread t1(listen);
    while (true) {
        qmutex.lock();
        if (!queue.empty()) {
           //There's something in the queue, read it/take a copy
           queue.pop();
        }
        qmutex.unlock();

        // Respond to input
        // Continue work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `cin` supports non-blocking I/O operations or timeouts.

Here's an example of the lower-level way to accomplish the task, using `select()` and file descriptors.  This program will immediately print to `stdout` any text it receives from `stdin`, and also wake up every 5 seconds (even if no text is received from `stdin`) just to print a fixed message.  You can modify the wakeup timeout to whatever you like (including zero for an instantaneous-poll behavior), and/or add more file descriptors for it to react to if you prefer a more event-driven approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

static void RegisterFileDescriptor(int fd, int & maxFD, fd_set & fdset)
{
   FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
   if (fd > maxFD) maxFD = fd;
}

int main()
{
    const int stdinFileno = fileno(stdin);

    // This call is just here so that our parent process will immediately see any
    // text lines that we print to stdout.  If you're only reading from stdin and never
    // writing responses back to stdout, then it's not really necessary.
    (void) setlinebuf(stdout);

    fd_set readSet;
    while(true)
    {
       int maxFD = -1;

       FD_ZERO(&readSet);
       RegisterFileDescriptor(stdinFileno, maxFD, readSet);

       // If you want to react to incoming data on any other
       // file descriptors as well, you could call
       // RegisterFileDescriptor on them here

       struct timeval timeoutDelay = {5, 0};  // let's force a wakeup every 5 seconds

       if (select(maxFD+1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeoutDelay) < 0)
       {
          perror("select");
          break;
       }

       printf("select() returned!\n");

       if (FD_ISSET(stdinFileno, &readSet))
       {
          char buf[512];
          if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) printf("Read from stdin: [%s]\n", buf);
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```